# I need to transfer money from user to user using PayPal, from within my site

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I need to transfer money from user to user using PayPal, from within my site.

The scenario is:

The user can sigup with paypal in my site. The signuped user can able to transfer the money to another paypal user within my site without redirect to paypal login.

Currently i done with user sigup with paypal. its worked fine but when user trying to send amount to another paypal user its redirecting to paypal site to send it.

I have gone through the paypal api Implicit Payment. But its working when the app email and sender email was same means transaction is done without redirect to paypal. but if the sender email was different means its redirecting to paypal to relogin and get confirmation to send amount .

User who signup with paypal. Should not be redirect to paypal again for tranfer money. how we can do this. is it possible ? please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may integrate seamless checkout feature on your website, which gives customers the ability to directly checkout using their PayPal account. Once logged in to your website through Log In with PayPal, the buyer can seamlessly checkout with PayPal without the need to log in to PayPal again. [[Seamless checkout]](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/seamless-checkout/)

If your website works as a marketplace, you could refer [Parallel payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/) using Express Checkout.

Comment: I have tried as Seamless checkout. but the problem is some time it working and sometimes its asking me to login for payment. But using Seamless checkout i don't want to send payment to merchant. I need only to user to user.
In parallel payments amount can be send to merchant also.
Please let me know you comments.
Am looking only user yo user.

Comment: If the LIPP session is timeout, the seamless checkout will not work anymore. If this is not the above case, you may reach Paypal support team to look into further.Based on your business model-user to user, Parallel payment will be suitable as you could set up one or more users as the receivers. Pass the field PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID to identity the receiver account.